# Fifth minute today close

Tags: pine-script, price

I was wondering if there is a way to get today's 5th minute bar close price in any timeframe?
It seems that close price is not held but is a moving variable based on input tick.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess it is more or less like get the first bar's close in the 5th minute timeframe period ?

Comment: You should include code samples of what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Well, if you use `close` as it is, it refers to the current bar, which has not been closed yet. And the value of `close` refers to the last price action on that bar. This is way it is a "moving variable" because the price is changing. If you want to access to previous close values, [history reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator).

Comment: Also, have a look at the [security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function for context switching and [this](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#other-timeframes-mtf) awesome faq and code on multiple time frames.